# MySQL Select where column greater than or equal to closest past date from given date

Tags: mysql, date, select

### TABLE

```
Table:

Id             Date
1            01-10-15
2            01-01-16
3            01-03-16
4            01-06-16
5            01-08-16
```

Given two dates **startdate** 01-02-16 and **enddate** 01-05-16. I need to get the data from the table such that it returns all data between the closest past date from **startdate** and closest future date from **enddate** including the two dates. So the result will look like this.

```
Result:

Id             Date
2            01-01-16
3            01-03-16
4            01-06-16
```

**What I am doing**

What I am doing now is fetching the whole data and removing from the array results less than closest **fromdate** and greater than closest **enddate**

**What I want**

What I want is to do this in query itself so that I  don't have to fetch the whole data from table each time.

Comment: read about `between`

Comment: And store dates under a date data type

Comment: @Jens need to include the closest past date and closest future date to fromdate and enddate respectively.

Comment: How do you define **closest**? What's the threshold difference between the `startDate & closest date` or `endDate & closest date`?

Comment: @1000111 Here closest means the most recent past date to fromdate eg: in Jan, Feb , March, April. Feb is closest past date to March. Likewise regarding end date

Comment: I was thinking for a particular data set where dates are too far apart from start date and end date. But according to your logic these too far dates are still considered to be the closest dates. @user1492669

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you column's type is `date`, use `union` can do it:

```
(select * from yourtable where `date` <= '2016-01-02' order by `date` desc limit 1)
-- This query will get record which is closest past date from startdate
union
(select * from yourtable where `date` => '2016-01-05' order by `date` asc limit 1)
-- This query will get record which is closest future date from enddate
union
(select * from yourtable where `date` between '2016-01-02' and '2016-01-05')
```

[<kbd>Demo Here</kbd>](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6437d/3)

Comment: Hello Reno! will this query return the in between dates of start date and end date? Isn't it restricting it to 1 row using limit 1? And you might get duplicate dates as well.

Comment: Please add a brief explanation of how this query works specially the **closest date** getting queries. Otherwise it's okay. +1 :)

Comment: @1000111 Sure, why not. Thanks. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Imaging your date is in YYYY-mm-dd

```
## get rows within the dates
SELECT * FROM tab WHERE ymd BETWEEN :start_date AND :end_date
## get one row closest to start date

UNION
SELECT * FROM tab WHERE ymd < :start_date ORDER BY ymd DESC LIMIT 1
## get one row closest to end date

UNION
SELECT * FROM tab WHERE ymd > :end_date   ORDER BY ymd      LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Please add a brief explanation of how this query works specially the **closest date** getting queries. Otherwise it's okay. +1 :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Select *
From 
    dTable 
Where 
     [Date] 
Between 
       (Select 
              Max(t1.Date) 
        From 
            dTable t1 
        Where 
             t1.date <startdate) And    
       (Select 
              Min(t2.Date) 
        From 
             dTable t2 
        Where 
             t2.date >enddate)
```

Comment: I think it will omit the closest dates because of *<=* and *>=*.

Comment: Now it's okay. :) Better ad an explanation of how this query works. +1

Answer (score 0):

If Date is String, STR_TO_DATE and DATEDIFF can be used here.

```
SELECT  id,  Date
FROM tab
where
STR_TO_DATE(Date, '%d-%m-%y') BETWEEN('2016-02-01')AND('2016-05-01')
or 
id = (SELECT id FROM tab
where STR_TO_DATE(Date, '%d-%m-%y') > '2016-05-01'
ORDER BY DATEDIFF(STR_TO_DATE(Date, '%d-%m-%y'), '2016-05-01') Limit 1)
or 
id = (SELECT id FROM tab
where STR_TO_DATE(Date, '%d-%m-%y') < '2016-02-01'
ORDER BY DATEDIFF('2016-02-01', STR_TO_DATE(Date, '%d-%m-%y')) Limit 1)
```